# Google Sheets - Display Note From Reference Sheet Using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello Helpful Strangers

I am busy building an inventory location system using Google Sheets. I have two tabs:

**Tab 1: "Basket"**
This shows items as chosen by the customer

| Basket 1 | Basket 2 | Basket 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Banana | Pear | Apple |
| Orange | Orange | Pear |
| Lettuce | Cucumber | Cucumber |
| Broccoli | Lettuce | Broccoli |
| Pumpkin |  |  |

**Tab 2: "Data"**
This shows more details about each item such as category and price.

| Item | Category | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Fruit | $1 |
| Banana | Fruit | $1.50 |
| Pear | Fruit | $1.25 |
| Orange | Fruit | $1 |
| Cucumber | Vegetable | $1.33 |
| Lettuce | Vegetable | $2 |
| Broccoli | Vegetable | $2.10 |
| Pumpkin | Vegetable | $3 |

I would like to use Google Sheets' notes feature to display the category and price on the Basket sheet when I hover over an item as in the image below:

[image]

I have no experience in Apps Script and require some assistance please.

An added bonus would be to auto-size (trim) the note size according to the displayed content.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please prodivde [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of code you've tried so far. Also you can't dynamically update notes like that on hover, although you can update the notes dynamically when user select the particular cell.

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat:**

This solution is very specific to the data and 2 sheets, Basket and Data you provide above. I would suggest you study the app script carefully before using it.

**Sample Script**

```
function addNotes() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var bsh = ss.getSheetByName("Basket");
    var dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
    var bValues = bsh.getDataRange().getValues();
    bValues.shift();  // remove the first row
    var dValues = dsh.getDataRange().getValues();
    dValues.shift();  // remove the first row
    dValues = dValues.map( 
      row => row[0]+" - "+row[1]+" - $"+(( typeof row[2] === "number" ) ? row[2].toFixed(2) : row[2] )
    );
    var notes = [];
    bValues.forEach( row => {
        temp = [];
        row.forEach( col => {
          temp.push( dValues.find( item => item.includes(col) ) );
        } );
        notes.push(temp);
      } );
    bsh.getRange(2,1,notes.length,notes[0].length).setNotes(notes);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**References:**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNotes(Object)